# Embedding flash .swf in html; Flashplayer version problems

Tags: html, plugins, browser, flash

I have a flash application embedded on an html file.

When publishing my swf file, the max target flash player is 11.2.

If the browser I use to open the html has the latest player (Shockwave Flash 11.5) then my application does not run properly.

Is there a way in the html code to force the usage of an old flash player ? Any other solution ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 11.5 there are some security updates and fixes.

I was having a security error. The fix was to add the crossdomain.xml file to my server, which my flash app was contacting.

about policy : http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but there is no way to target an older flash version. The browser will use whichever instance of flash that is installed on the system. The only real solution is to modify your app.